# Display divs on the same line with overflow

Tags: asp.net, css

I got a probleme on my project. I need to display some divs on just one line with overflow.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="divHeaderHorizon" runat="server" style="width:1500px; height:50px; margin-left:200px; margin-top:20px; position:absolute; background-color:red; overflow:auto;">
   <div id="divMonthHeader" runat="server" style="height:20px; background-color:blue; position:relative; margin-top:5px;">

   </div>

   <div id="divDayHeader" runat="server" style="height:20px; background-color:blue; position:relative;">

   </div>
</div>
```

In the "divMonthHeader" I got from 6 to 24 divs with a width that depends on the number of days in the month.

Here is my C# code :

```
HtmlGenericControl divMonth = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divMonth.ID = date.ToString("MMMM", culture);
divMonth.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "white");
divMonth.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "inline-block");
divMonth.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, ((DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month) * 35) + ( 2 * DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month))) + "px");
divMonth.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
divMonth.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft, "2px");
divMonth.Style.Add("float", "left");
```

Comment: Are you trying to draw a bar graph or do a data-visualisation by doing the above?

Comment: @user3240361 : I'm trying to do a header bar for a scheduler and I want that when I move the scrollbar of the scheduler this div with the Months and Days move the same. But for now the Month display one under the over.

Answer (score 0):

in css this is possible by using `white-space:nowrap`

```
#divHeaderHorizon
{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

and make your inner-divs `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I'm so dumb...

I only need to put a width higher on divMonthHeader and divDayHeader than on divHeaderHorizon and it works ...

Sorry for wasting your time guys.